# copy uiimageview origin to CGPoint

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, cgpoint

I am new to iPhone/Objective-C programming. I have a UIImageView *myImage whose x,y,width,height are set using CGRect with values (20,20,100,100) or whatever;

Q1) When I do the following why can't i fetch the origin values into CGPoint.

```
CGPoint myPoint = myImage.frame.origin;

NSLog(@"X:%f Y:%f",mypoint.x, mypoint.y) // Prints X: 0.0 and Y: 0.0 instead of X:20.0 and Y: 20.o
NSLog(@"X:%f Y:%f",myImage.frame.origin.x, myImage.frame.origin.x) // Prints X: 20.0 and Y: 20.0
```

The above NSLog statements do not print the expected values for myPoint but prints the right values for myImage.frame.origin. Why?

Q2) Also why can't I set @property to CGPoint ?

Answer (score 2):

1) Have you tried :

```
CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(myImage.fram.origin.x, myImage.frame.origin.y);
```

2) After som testing I have found that you should be able to have your CGPoint as a property like this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {

CGPoint myPoint;
...
}
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint myPoint;

...
@end
```

And then:

```
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize myPoint;

...

@end
```

that worked for me.

(I must admit I have not yet understood the (nonatomic) and if it is necessary but as long as it works...)